# How to recover the deleted or moved data from a particular directory in Linux Environment?

Tags: data-recovery

I accidentally moved some files from /home/name/Pictures/ directory from my opensuse 11.4 machine to flash drive. Is there a way to recover the data? I lost the data from my flash drive.

Answer (score 1):

Probably no.

Many (most?) Linux desktops have a "wastebasket".  If you delete files using the GUI, you should be able to recover them from the wastebasket GUI:

There are also tools like TestDisk or ExtUndelete that might be able to help you:

- http://www.linux.org/threads/undelete-files-on-linux-systems.4316/
- http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/

Finally, here are some other links that might (might!) help:

- http://www.linux.org/threads/undelete-files-on-linux-systems.4316/
- https://superuser.com/questions/150027/how-to-recover-a-removed-file-under-linux
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery
- http://www.smashingapps.com/2011/08/11/5-must-have-file-recovery-tools-for-linux-users.html

But frankly, your best choices for Linux are the same as for Windows: keep backups of anything you really care about!